# HTML 5 required validation for .NET Web Forms dropdown list and date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, datepicker

I have two controls on my aspx page which I'm unable to validate with html 5:

```
             <asp:DropDownList ID="dropCountry" required runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

 <input id="datepicker" class="datepicker" required runat="server" readonly="true"/>
```

These are the scripts included for jquery date picker and jquery code to show the date picker:

```
<script src="datepicker/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<link href="datepicker/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
      $(function ()
      {
          $(".datepicker").datepick();
      });
  </script>
```

For some reason, these two controls won't validate when I click "submit" button... Any ideas why ??

Thanks for the help!

P.S. These are the errors in console:

[image]

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: it could be preventing the datepick library from working properly though

Comment: Yes there are couple of errors, I've updated my question, can you see?

Comment: Added an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove runat='server' on the control as I think this may be changing the ID via .NET at runtime.

**Edit:** Target it via class and not ID, like so...

```
<input required runat="server" class="datepicker" readonly="true"/>

<script>
  $(function ()
  {
      $(".datepicker").datepick();
  });
```

Comment: Okay one second I'll try it like this

Comment: You may want to give it a better class name too, not datepicker, like I suggest! :-)

Comment: P.S. I've updated my first question showing how I edited by using ur answer... Its sIt doesn't validates it again :/

Comment: It doesnt validates the controll still using "required" tag... It just skips it for some reason I've updated the errors from console in my question. Can u take a look ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107169/discussion-between-perkes456-and-zink).